# Is there a package naming convention for Hibernate Model classes?

Tags: java, hibernate

Should I put Models in a package like this:

```
com.mycompany.myproject.persistence.models
```

Or is there a different convention?

Comment: I believe you should stick with "model". As hibernate docs says: "...useful with object-oriented domain models and business logic in...". As you can see, the models are part of the domain, as the business logic and etc. The "domain" is the whole. Also, you stay close to the "model" definition in MVC pattern (model, view, controller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, or you can put them under `domain`.
Please refer examples given in the [hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/)